# How to change font color for data in database to print in pdf like for absent=red color and present=green?

Tags: php, pdf, mysqli

I want to change the font color of the text in PDF to absent is to red and present is to green. How can i add those in these codes? Need help for a beginner. Thanks alot.
Btw, I used fpdf to make the output a downloadable pdf.

```
<?php
//include connection file 
include "db.php";
include_once('fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF
{
// Page header
function Header()
{
    // Logo
    // $this->Image('https://i2.wp.com/tutorialswebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/cropped-LOGO-1.png',10,10,50);
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',13);
    // Move to the right
    $this->Cell(80);
    // Title
    $this->Cell(80,10,'ICT-5 Attendance',1,0,'C');
    // Line break
    $this->Ln(20);
}

// Page footer
function Footer()
{
    // Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
    $this->SetY(-15);
    // Arial italic 8
    $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
    // Page number
    $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
}
}
```

Should i add that in here?

```
$display_heading = array('roll_number'=>'Roll Number', 'student_name'=> 'Name of Student', 'attendance_status'=> 'Attendance Status','id'=> 'DATABASE ID Num.','date'=> 'Date');

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id, student_name, roll_number, attendance_status, date FROM attendance_records WHERE date ='$_POST[date]'") or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
$header = mysqli_query($conn, "SHOW columns FROM attendance_records WHERE field != 'created_on'");

$pdf = new PDF();
//header
$pdf->AddPage();
//foter page
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
foreach($header as $heading) {
$pdf->Cell(39,10,$display_heading[$heading['Field']],1);
}
foreach($result as $row) {
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','I',8.5);
$pdf->Ln();
foreach($row as $column)
$pdf->Cell(39,10,$column,1);
}
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: btw, the column for absent/present is on attendance_status

Comment: curious why the use of two sql queries - the second appears to only find the column names - presumably you are not aware of  `mysqli_result::fetch_fields()` to return column names? Presumably you can use `SetTextColor` ?

Comment: sorry sir? i'm just new to php and just watch a tutorial about having pdf output from database, it worked fine now, but just wondering if i can change the font color of text under the attendance status column as it is a essential one for our system were working on

Comment: what values are stored for `attendance_status`? 1/0, true/false etc?

Comment: and i also used the first query to have the identification of dates as they must be on that specific date

Comment: Absent/Present sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about this but perhaps it will help. I've never used `fPDF` but a quick look at the [documentation](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/index.php) suggests that `SetTextColor` would be the method you need.

```
foreach( $result as $row ) {
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','I',8.5);
    $pdf->Ln();
    foreach($row as $column) {
        switch( $row['attendance_status'] ){
            case 'Absent': $pdf->SetTextColor(255,0,0); break;
            case 'Present':$pdf->SetTextColor(0,255,0);break;
        }
        $pdf->Cell(39,10,$column,1);
    }
}
```

To change ( hopefully ) just the word `Absent/Present` try this perhaps:

```
foreach( $result as $row ) {
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','I',8.5);
    $pdf->Ln();

    foreach($row as $fieldname => $column) {
        if( $fieldname=='attendance_status' ){
            switch( $row['attendance_status'] ){
                case 'Absent': $pdf->SetTextColor(255,0,0); break;
                case 'Present':$pdf->SetTextColor(0,255,0);break;
            }       
        } else {
            $pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);  #default to BLACK
        }

        $pdf->Cell(39,10,$column,1);
    }
}
```

Comment: sir under/after which line should i add those? hehe

Comment: sir i think there's something wrong, it says( Illegal string offset 'attendance_status' in...)

Comment: ok - wondered about that...  what is the value of `$column` at that point in the loop - is it an array or the value of a field???

Comment: sir i think it is a value of a field as it shows the data under the columns

Comment: ok - it should I think have been `$row['attendance_status']` ~ my silly mistake.. try again

Comment: it worked so well sir. im so happy, but just all the rows are colored based on (absent/present) i just want to color the data 'Present'/'Absent'. BTW SO MUCH THANKS